# How remove product links from order received page in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce, hyperlink, customization

I have a WooCommerce website for digital downloads as PDFs.

On the *Order Received* page (attached), users are accidentally clicking on the product links (two on the left side) instead of the PDF link (blue box link at top-right, under "Downloads").

Users appear to be focusing on left side of page, "blind" to the appropriate link.

So, my best solution is to remove the the product hyperlinks (text ok). How do I do this please?

Screenshot of Order Received page showing two identical product links on right side and the correct PDF link on top-right:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment @7uc1f3r.  I posted here because of similar questions that were answered without issue.  Anyway, I found the answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/300400/replace-product-link-with-just-product-name-on-woocommerce-downloads-page

Answer (score 1):

Please add **woocommerce_order_item_permalink** filter in theme function file
Ex. add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_permalink', '__return_false' );